# how can i fix this null in firebase?

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to import data from FirebaseDatabase and it is working but not with this class , when i try to get it data it give my a null value   , and this is the class it called RoomsAvailable can any one tell me how why i get null value and how can i fix it.

```
public class RoomsAvailable {

private int onePerson;
private int twoPerson;
private int threePerson;
private int fourPerson;



public RoomsAvailable() {

}
public RoomsAvailable(int onePerson, int twoPerson, int threePerson, int fourPerson) {
    this.onePerson = onePerson;
    this.twoPerson = twoPerson;
    this.threePerson = threePerson;
    this.fourPerson = fourPerson;
}

public int getOnePerson() {
    return onePerson;
}

public void setOnePerson(int onePerson) {
    this.onePerson = onePerson;
}

public int getTwoPerson() {
    return twoPerson;
}

public void setTwoPerson(int twoPerson) {
    this.twoPerson = twoPerson;
}

public int getThreePerson() {
    return threePerson;
}

public void setThreePerson(int threePerson) {
    this.threePerson = threePerson;
}

public int getFourPerson() {
    return fourPerson;
}

public void setFourPerson(int fourPerson) {
    this.fourPerson = fourPerson;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RoomsAvailable{" +
            "onePerson=" + onePerson +
            ", twoPerson=" + twoPerson +
            ", threePerson=" + threePerson +
            ", fourPerson=" + fourPerson +
            '}';
}
```

}

and this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabaseReference.child("0/"+"hotels").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); i++) {
                Hotel hotel = dataSnapshot.child(i + "").getValue(Hotel.class);
                hotelList.add(hotel);

                Log.d(TAG, hotel.getId() + "\n");
                Log.d(TAG, hotel.getCityId() + "\n");
                Log.d(TAG, hotel.getName() + "\n");


                Log.d(TAG, hotel.getRoomsAvailable() + "\n");

            }
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cities_recyclerview);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HotelAdapter(getApplicationContext(), hotelList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCreate:Failed to read hotelList.", databaseError.toException());

        }



    });


}
```

and this is my Firebase Database

[image]

Q: what is the problem ?

Q: How can I Fix it  ?

Comment: Please show us your `Hotel` class as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting always `null` because you are declaring the `hotelList` outside `onDataChange()` method. This is happening due the asynchronous behaviour of this method, which is called even before you are adding those hotels to the list. So in order to solve this, please move the declaration of the list inside `onDataChange()` or if you want to use it outside, see my answer form this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Your code should look like this:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("0/"+"hotels").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount(); i++) {
            Hotel hotel = dataSnapshot.child(i + "").getValue(Hotel.class);
            hotelList.add(hotel);

            Log.d(TAG, hotel.getId() + "\n");
            Log.d(TAG, hotel.getCityId() + "\n");
            Log.d(TAG, hotel.getName() + "\n");
            Log.d(TAG, hotel.getRoomsAvailable() + "\n");
        }
        Log.d("TAG", hotelList);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cities_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HotelAdapter(getApplicationContext(), hotelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate:Failed to read hotelList.", databaseError.toException());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u try like this

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final List<Hotel> hotelList = new ArrayList<>();
mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabaseReference.child("0/"+"hotels").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            hotelList = (List<Hotel>) dataSnapshot.getValue(Hotel.class);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cities_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HotelAdapter(getApplicationContext(), hotelList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate:Failed to read hotelList.", databaseError.toException());

    }



});
```

}